# Why do Objective-C objects still exist after they are dealloced?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have this code here...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Chip.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Chip *chip = [[Chip alloc] init];

    [chip release]; //Chip should be gone

    NSLog(@"%@", chip);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Why does printing out the chip after it is released still gives me the description.  Should it not be removed at this point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chip` *is* gone. You're just talking to its ghost.

Add a `dealloc` override that logs the call. You should see that the deallocation occurs as expected. The object is released, but nothing else has happened to trash the memory and your call happens not to trespass where it would cause trouble.

Comment: I did add that before [super dealloc] is called and it prints out that it is deallocated, but it still is able to print what the object's description was.  How is that possible if dealloc is called?

Comment: Upon being deallocated the memory occupied by chip is flagged by the OS as available for future allocations. Nothing else comes along, so nothing else gets it. Dealloc doesn't clear memory. Accesses to deallocated pointers in C have an undefined effect and are not required to throw any sort of exception. You probably own something else within that segment of memory, so the whole lot is still accessible to your program. Memory tends to be owned in blocks of, for example, 4kb so that the MMU doesn't need unreasonable amounts of storage to gate access.

Comment: @Tommy, thanks a lot for the explanation.  So dealloc just sets that block of memory to be overridden at any point?  So things can still point to it, but if the memory has been overridden by something else, then it will cause problems?  Thanks

Comment: Things can still point to it, since a pointer is just an address — usually a 32bit or 64bit number. But reading it after deallocation may produce any result, including the same result as if you hadn't dealloced and your program crashing immediately. That's why dangling pointers (especially if you write to, rather than reading them) are often one of the hardest things to debug. Debugging systems like Valgrind can put every allocated object on a separate page so that you always get an exception on a bad access, at the cost of your program running extremely slowly because of poor caching.

Answer (score 0):

The line:`[comp setChip:chip];` increments the retain count of chip to 2, since comp is also now retaining chip, so when you release chip, it still has a retain count of 1.

Comment: It's also possible that the released memory hasn't been overwritten yet and still contains the same bytes to log.

Comment: @walkytalky: Ah, you're right, I missed that in the original post. I figured his setter implementation was retaining.

Comment: Reference counting comes into picture only when multiple instances pointing to same memory chunk. There is no such concept that same variable can point to different memory chunks when at different scopes. This will lead to memory leaks !

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As far as I'm aware, until the auto release pool has been drained, the object will still exist, it'll simply have a retain count of zero and hence be ripe for deletion. (In effect you're saying that you're no longer interested in the object, and that it can be deleted.)</strike>

Incidentally, whilst slightly off topic, if you make use of [NSZombieEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html), you'll be able to see a practical demonstration of what happens when you attempt to use the released object.

Comment: That only applies to objects that have been added to the autorelease pool (either explicitly or under the hood by some other method). Directly `alloc/init`-ed objects should be deallocated as soon as they get a `release` call on a retain count of 1. (Add usual disclaimers about never looking at retain counts here.)

Comment: @walkytalky Yup, hence my edit. (Time for me to back away from the keyboard, I think.) Would have culled this answer, but the NSZombie bit is of use, so simply edited.