# Was the object will survive even I areleased it once

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to know about release keyword. I allocated it once, and then I released it. then also the message was passed to that `object`. And it gives me output. But the retain count is `zero`. What is the reason behind this?

```
MyClass *obj=[[MyClass alloc]init];

[obj release];
[obj WhoAreYou];
```

I given "`NSLOG(@"It is the problem.");`"

I got the out put: It is the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do releases not happen right away in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819451/why-do-releases-not-happen-right-away-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/iphone-basics-memory-management/) link..a simple tutorial on memory management..It says

> You can think of release as saying
> relinquish ownership of this object,
> rather than destroy this object

That means when you release you are just losing your control over the object..You are not releasing it..Cocoa will release the variable if it is not referenced by anyone else